# Can I merge two databases into one in Mysql if they both have the same schema?

Tags: mysql

I have two databases in MySQL that already have data. they have exactly the same schema. I would like to merge those two databases into one only. I tried:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases database1 database2 database3 > database1_database2_da
```

However, when I try to open `database1_database2_da`, I only end up with data from one of the database, but not all of them. I also want to mention that the two databases have their records starting at 1, since they are automatically generated. Do you think there is a way to merge those two databases without losing data from any of them?

Comment: Do they have conflicting primary keys? You'd need to massage the data before you merge, or you'll get PK violations and/or dropped inserts when you insert the second dump.

Comment: I don't see any conflicting primary key, since I obtain only data from one data base as if it was overwriting the data from the second database.

Answer (score 16):

Run `mysqldump` on each database with the `--no-create-info` option to avoid writing schema information. Then run once on one database with the `--no-data` option. If you load all of these files sequentially into the same target database, this should work, barring any differences in schema between the two databases or duplicate primary keys.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-create-info database1 > database1.sql
mysqldump -u root -p --no-create-info database2 > database2.sql
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data database1 > schema.sql
```

After creating a new database, run

```
mysql -uroot -p -Ddatabase3 < schema.sql
mysql -uroot -p -Ddatabase3 < database1.sql
mysql -uroot -p -Ddatabase3 < database2.sql
```

This may also work. Don't have a Windows box to test on ATM

```
type schema.sql database1.sql database2.sql | mysql -uroot -p -Ddatabase3
```

Comment: Now, it says: "mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command,program or batch file." And I am actually in the directory containing schema.sql

Comment: Seems as though you don't have the MySQL command-line client installed (or at least, it's not in your path). You may want to try a GUI tool if you feel more comfortable. SQLyog is reasonably good http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list.

Comment: Isn't this going to break your relations in database? (the merged one)

Comment: If you have no duplicate primary keys, then it's a non-issue, a caveat which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: What's the solution when there are duplicate keys. Surely that would be the case if merging identical independent databases with tables using autoincrement primary keys and all starting at 1?

Comment: @iheanyi That depends on what you want to do. Of course if the databases are identical, just throw one of them away :) You could ignore duplicates with `--insert-ignore` when making the dump otherwise you'd have to think about how you want to reconcile things.

Comment: @MichaelMior The downside of that: you must always insert records for both databases in the same order, all tables must use an auto-incrementing primary key (you couldn't have the primary key be text for example), and you can't have foreign key relationships between tables. For my problem, I decided to go the composite key approach. The overhead is at database setup to ensure the unique to each database portion of the primary keys is set correctly but after that, you can merge without worries.