# Merge two MySql databases except duplicate PKs

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I have two databases with the same schema. For example database1 and database2; Now I need to combine them. I was trying to follow these answer:
[Can I merge two databases into one in Mysql if they both have the same schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526824/can-i-merge-two-databases-into-one-in-mysql-if-they-both-have-the-same-schema)
But I ve got an exception like this: `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 24: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`
So the question is simple: is there any way to merge two databases ignoring duplication of PKs of second DB? Or variant with overriding of conflict records by second DB? Both variants are acceptable.

Additional comment:
Talking about databases I mean exactly databases; I have two dupm files of DBs, and i need to deploy both of the to one, combined DB with data from first and second one. If some data would be lost - it is not problem. But i need to combine maximum data from both of the DATABASES! not tables

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.  Your meaning of "*merge*" is not clear.

Comment: When you say "databases" do you really mean tables?

Comment: Are the primary keys just auto_increment IDs, or can they be columns with real information like usernames? If they're real columns, how should the duplicates be resolved?

Comment: @Barmar duplicates coul be ignored or overriden. Both variants are OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--insert-ignore` option to `mysqldump`. That will cause it to write `INSERT IGNORE` commands to the dump file, instead of ordinary `INSERT` statements. This causes duplicate keys to be skipped when inserting, instead of causing an error.

Comment: it should look like this
`mysqldump -u root -p --insert-ignore --no-create-info database1 > database1.sql`

Comment: It seems like it worked! Thank you. Point as right answer